# Deploy Laravel 5.8 in Subfolder - Routes are not working properly

Tags: laravel, deployment, subdirectory

I recently uploaded my laravel projet to my domain in a subfolder called laravel.
I got it running, but when i click on the different sections, it goes to the home domain.

Example.

wwww.mydomain.com/laravel --> that works
I hit con "about us" and instead of going to www.mydomain.com/laravel/about

it goes to www.mydomain.com/about.

How can i configure the routes? from htaccess?  Any solution?

thanks

Comment: Hi Rodolfo! Could you please add what you've tried so far? I think your issue could be solved with .htaccess changes.

Comment: Hi. thanks for your answer. So far i´ve tried.
1. Changing the routes on web.php - didnt work
2. Adding some functions in htaccess, didnt work

What i see, is that the routes from register and Login are working (the routes that laravel creates) but the ones i made don´t work.

You can see my projetc in www.rodolfodietl.com.ar/laravel